# Dual head configuration with two touchscreens in Linux

Tags: linux, x11, multi-monitor, input

As a part of my current project I need to set up a **Linux-based** workstation with two monitors, both of which are multitouch-enabled (ViewSonic VX2258wm, Quanta touch panel). So, naturally, I set up a dual-head configuration and I connect the touchpanels using USB cables. While dual-head output works just fine, the operating system doesn't differentiate between the first and the second touch panels (so, if the first monitor is active, and I touch the second, the mouse pointer moves to the corresponding coordinates of the first monitor). I understand that the X server knows nothing about which touch panel corresponds to which monitor (since those are logically and, as a matter of fact, physically, different devices).

Does anyone know if it is possible to make such configuration work right? Any suggestions, hints, kludges will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to differentiate between the two input devices and map them to the displays, but you will end up doing a full manual configuration of your x.org server. I did something like that many years ago, but the config files I used are long gone and I don't remember the details, only that it worked. Also, I have no clue if x.org is able to handle any kind of multitouch.

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup the two input devices manually in `xorg.conf` and specify the offset for each one so that they map to the correct location in your overall X screen setup.

Each input driver will need to be specifically mapped by to the ID of the device it corresponds to. Not specifying this will cause the driver to take over ANY matching devices.

After you have two separate input devices working, you just need to use the corresponding option for whatever the driver is to specify the coordinate space or offset.